# How to get app widget size?

Tags: android, resize, size, android-appwidget

I have an Android app widget and I would like to extend it to support several sizes and also re-sizable with Honeycomb.

The problem is that I need to know what is the size of the widget , so I can know how much content I can put in it.

How do I read the app widget size?

I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know it's old question, but there's a newer answer to it (that I believe was not available on the time, as it is API 16 and up only):

you can call:

```
Bundle options = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId);
```

that will give the same options that is passed to your receiver during

```
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Bundle newOptions)
```

with this `Bundle` options you can query for the sizing using the constants:

```
AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT
AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH
AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT
AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH
```

Remembering that Samsung likes to be different, so you probably need a special Handler for TouchWiz (code bellow copied directly from my app):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  if (intent == null || intent.getAction() == null)
     return;
  // I FUCKING HATE SAMSUNG!
  if (intent.getAction().contentEquals("com.sec.android.widgetapp.APPWIDGET_RESIZE") &&
     Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
     handleTouchWiz(context, intent);
  }
  super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@TargetApi(16)
private void handleTouchWiz(Context context, Intent intent) {
  AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

  int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra("widgetId", 0);
  int widgetSpanX = intent.getIntExtra("widgetspanx", 0);
  int widgetSpanY = intent.getIntExtra("widgetspany", 0);

  if (appWidgetId > 0 && widgetSpanX > 0 && widgetSpanY > 0) {
     Bundle newOptions = new Bundle();
     // We have to convert these numbers for future use
     newOptions.putInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_HEIGHT, widgetSpanY * 74);
     newOptions.putInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MIN_WIDTH, widgetSpanX * 74);

     onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, newOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: how did you come up with widgetSpan * 74? Just trial and error? Do you know majic number for max_height??

Comment: sorry the `handleTouchWiz` was directly copied from some other SO answer. I have no idea, where it comes from.

Comment: Just tested on Galaxy S6, the intent is never received, but the onAppWidgetOptionsChanged is called with valid parameters, so Samsung seems to have fixed this.

Comment: Trying this on a tablet, i just noticed it doesn't fire on orientation change. Plus even if you force it to fire with a reisze the values seems to be wrong ( the same as in portrait )